# Simple password authentication to the whole site in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4

I had a PHP application which I have rewritten in Rails. The only thing I haven't achieved is the authentication. I am the only valid user, so I simply compared form POST input against a hardcoded hash. (So a gem with signup etc is overkill)

The closest equivalent I have is the `http_basic_authenticate_with` command in the `application_controller.rb` file. However I prefer to have the password field on the site, and also not have to enter a username.

Here is a rough psuedo-code of what the PHP looked like. What is the best translation of this to Ruby on Rails?

```
<?php
session_start();

if (! empty($_GET['logout']))
{
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: ?');
    die;
}
else if (! empty($_SESSION['logged_in']))
{
  // application code

  ?>
  <a href="?logout=true">Log out</a>
  <?php
}

else if (! empty($_POST['password']) && sha1($_POST['password']) === 'abc')
{
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
}

else
{
    ?>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <input type="submit" value="Log in">
    </form>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Authentication**

You'll be looking to set a `session` value, which your user can carry around the site (allowing you test against is to determine various interactivity).

It seems you do this already in PHP, so I'll translate your code below; however you may also wish to look at [how `Devise` do this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/search?q=authentication&ref=cmdform) - as since this is the most widely used authentication Gem in Rails, they're obviously doing something right.

The beauty of Rails is since it allows the [sessions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#what-are-sessions-questionmark) to work throughout your app, you'll be able to keep someone logged in even if they visit a multitude of pages

--

**Framework**

Your current code is a simple script; this will need to be modularized for use with Rails MVC structure. This is achieved using `controllers` & `actions` - which are accessed by `routes`. `Devise` uses a [`Sessions` controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :sessions

#app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
Class SessionsController < ApplicationController
   def create
       sessions[:user][:authentication] = SecureRandom.hex(8)
   end

   def destroy #-> this will use the DELETE HTTP Verb
       session[:user][:authentication].delete
       redirect_to root_path
   end
end
```

If you want to check if a user is signed in, all you'll need to do is check for the `session[:user][:authentication]` variable, which can be handled in a `helper`:

```
#app/helpers/authentication_helper.rb
class AuthenticationHelper
    def user_signed_in?
        session[:user][:authentication].present?
    end
end
```

This does several important things to consider:

> 1. You need to keep it as modular as possible
> 2. You need to ensure no passwords are persisted *anywhere* but in the db (even then they should be hashed)
> 3. You need to keep it as DRY as possible

Obviously a very brief overview - I can explain more if you need?

Comment: Thanks for this response. The reason I thought that a gem like devise, or anything which uses a database model was overkill is because I am the only valid user to this application. But your answer helps with sessions etc so I will try it out soon.

Comment: I ended up using Devise with the [single user mode](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Set-up-devise-as-a-single-user-system)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can translate this directly... You should create a sessions_controller where you can set up your login function, there you can evaluate if the params[:password] is equal to "abc" and create the cookie for the session, also create the logout method for destroying it and you have to create the routes for these methods.
You may want to create a helper in your application helper that checks if the cookie exist for displaying the form only if need it, let me know if this answer is enough or tell me witch parts are giving you troubles, regards

Comment: i forget another thing, you should have a before_filter in the controllers that prevent entering to the pages you don't want without login

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know or change codes into rails. check this out. 
I know this one can help you, So that you can focus rails codes

**Source:**https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0k6DFIStFY